# Is it worth checking value with select before updating

Tags: mysql

I have a `tinyint` boolean value in my row that is `0` by default and `1` whenever a specific thing happens. After it's `1`, it's always gonna stay `1`.
Now that specific thing can happen for each row many times, but I only need to update the value to `1` once.

Is it worth doing a `SELECT`, check the value and only if the value is `0`, trigger the `UPDATE`?

Also would maybe this

```
UPDATE table SET lock='1' WHERE id='100' AND lock='0'
```

be better than

```
UPDATE table SET lock='1' WHERE id='100'
```

for my situation?

Comment: Don't enclose numbers in single quotes, that's for strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's worth for several reasons:

- You might benefit for indexes on that column.
- It might seem to be a pointless update for cases when it's already `1`, but it might execute a trigger on the updating table.
- Avoid logging additional rows from the update operation. Even if the previous value matches the new one, the database still logs the operation (different would be assigning the value of it's same column `lock` which would be skipped in this case).

Comment: @EzLo are you answering yes to the question about using a pre-UPDATE SELECT statement, or yes to the question about including an extra condition in the UPDATE statement's WHERE clause? Or are you saying he should do both?

Answer (score 6):

Well, ["13.2.11 UPDATE Syntax"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) suggests, that no writing is done, when the value doesn't actually change.

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.

So the extended `WHERE` clause isn't needed to prevent unnecessary writes.

But you might get a tiny performance benefit from the extended `WHERE` clause as if not record to update was found, the logic to check, if the row actually needs to be changed won't run. But really, that's tiny.

And the effort for retrieval is there in either way. You can only try to support it with indexes (on `id` and `lock` (compound) for the extended version and on `id` for the other).

Answer (score 5):

EzLo's got you covered with a good list of positives, and I'm going to toss out just one negative. I don't think it applies to YOUR case, but I'm recording this here for other folks who might read this answer later for their own uses.

If your query might update multiple fields, then there's going to be a cost to building all these different queries:

Say we're only updating someone's last name:

```
UPDATE dbo.Users 
  SET LastName = 'Smith' 
  WHERE id='100' AND LastName = 'Jones';
```

But say we're also updating their last name and address:

```
UPDATE dbo.Users 
  SET LastName = 'Smith',
      StreetAddress = '123 Main Street',
      City = 'San Francisco',
      State = 'CA'
  WHERE id='100' 
    AND LastName = 'Jones'
    AND City = 'New York'
    AND State = 'NY';
```

To build a query like that, you're going to need to do a lot of equality checking in your app code. Plus, to make matters worse, you're going to end up bloating the plan cache with lots of different update strings that get executed when different combinations of parameters are used - because sometimes we only update LastName, sometimes we update LastName and City, sometimes we update City and State but not LastName, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is not worth doing a SELECT beforehand and could even decrease the performance of your System.
Your RDBMS needs to do this SELECT (searching the row that needs to be updated) anyway when you UPDATE. The UPDATE itself is (compared to the search) negligibly fast.
Costs and overhead (network latency + your check whether to update or not) is for two operations (SELECT + UPDATE) much, much higher than simply call UPDATE alone.

It was stated, you would benefit from indexes. This is not the case, because the first (and only) time you set 0 to 1 the index got already rebuilt.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

- No TRIGGERs
- No Replication
- `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table; that is, only one row matches `id=100` and `id` is indexed.

Then

- Do not do the `SELECT` -- it is doing something that the `UPDATE` will do.
- Do not do the `SELECT` -- KISS.
- `AND lock='0'` is optional since the `id=100` is sufficient to limit the filtering to a single row.  (If you expected multiple rows to match, then the `AND` would *probably* be beneficial, and it *might* benefit from an index starting will `lock`.)

Think of it this way:

- All proposed formulations require looking at one row.
- Fetching a row to look at it is a moderately costly.
- Two queries is more costly than one.
- *Your* programming time is even more costly, so KISS.

A side note (addressing one of the Comments):

- `id = '100'` is turned into `id = 100` during parsing; so no significant performance difference.  The index (eg, PK) on `id` is used in either case.
- `varchar_col = 100` is *bad*; every row must be looked at to see if `varchar_col` converts to the number `100`.  No index on `varchar_col` is not useful.